# Flutter abstract class type exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an abstract class called `NotificationModel` and I extend in two classes. When i try to add in a List of type `List<NotificationModel>` works for only one type (If i had one type works good but when I add another that extends the same `NotificationModel` I get an error). The error is the next:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> Unhandled error type 'AndroidNotificationsModel' is not a subtype of
> type 'ApiNotificationModel' of 'element' occurred in Instance of
> 'NotificationBloc'.

NotificationModel abstract class:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class NotificationsModel extends Equatable {

  final String id, title, body, image;
  final bool viewed;

  NotificationsModel({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.image, this.viewed,});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [this.id];
}
```

Class that extends class:

```
  class ApiNotificationModel extends NotificationsModel {

  final InvestmentOpportunityModel investmentOpportunityModel;

  ApiNotificationModel({
    id,
    title,
    body,
    image,
    viewed,
    this.investmentOpportunityModel,
  }) : super(id: id, title: title, image: image, body: body, viewed: viewed);

  factory ApiNotificationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ApiNotificationModel(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
      image: json['image'],
      viewed: json['viewed'],
      investmentOpportunityModel: json['investment'] != null
          ? InvestmentOpportunityModel.fromJson(json['investment'])
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```

The other class that extends:

```
class AndroidNotificationsModel extends NotificationsModel {

  AndroidNotificationsModel({id, opportunityId, title, body, image, viewed})
      : super(title: title, image: image, body: body, viewed: viewed, id: id);

  factory AndroidNotificationsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AndroidNotificationsModel(
      title: json['notification']['title'],
      body: json['notification']['body'],
      opportunityId: json['data']['id'],
      image: json['data']['image'],
    );
  }
}
```

Example:

```
// Works fine
List<NotificationModel> notifications = [ApiNotificationModel(), ApiNotificationModel()];

// Exception
notifications.add(AndroidNotificationsModel());
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It doesn't happen for me in DartPad.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an *s* in `NotificationsModel` at `List<NotificationModel> notifications`.

Comment: I have the problem when using the bloc. I will add the bloc code